# Program crashes when class is allocated on the heap, but not on the stack

Tags: c++, memory, heap-memory, stack-memory

Say I have a class called "Object " (very original, I know).  To initialize on the heap, I do:

```
Object object* = new Object ("arg");
```

To allocate on the stack:

```
Object object= Object("arg");
```

My program crashes when I use the former, and points me to this line of code in "new.cpp".

```
void *__CRTDECL operator new(size_t size) _THROW1(_STD bad_alloc)
    {       // try to allocate size bytes
    void *p;
    while ((p = malloc(size)) == 0)
            if (_callnewh(size) == 0)
            {       // report no memory
                    _THROW_NCEE(_XSTD bad_alloc, ); <---- this line
            }

    return (p);
    }
```

Knowing that, how would I go about finding the error and fixing it?  I assume this is corruption of heap memory of some kind?

Comment: The code you've shown is deep inside the standard library implementation of `new`. Show us your code instead, in a minimal and complete example which reproduces the issue (a.k.a. [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

Comment: When the crash is inside `new`, the problem is in the code that previously deallocated a piece of memory that has been used incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience, this typically happens when you corrupt your heap by doing something bad with a pointer like writing over the end of an object / buffer / array, or deleting an invalid pointer, or double deleting a pointer, or any other activity that corrupts the underlying data structure(s) used by the heap manager. You are observing a crash at a later stage which is just a symptom of something that happened previously.

Depending on your platform, you can check in Visual Studio by linking against the CRT debug heap, or on Linux using Electric Fence, Valgrind, etc.

Visual Studio heap debugging - [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z8h19c37(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z8h19c37%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Valgrind - http://valgrind.org/info/tools.html

Electric Fence and Valgrind are typically optional packages on Linux.